# ASR - Speech to Text - How to preprocess word transcript label of an audio file by aligning the label tensor to the lenght of the audio samples array

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, speech, data-preprocessing

I'm implementing a deep learning model for end-to-end automatic speech recognition task. I'm using the LibriSpeech corpus dataset. I encountered an issue in the preprocessing of the data set. As for the audio (.wav) data, I get the sampled audio and then extract the mfcc features, and this represents my input tensor. As for the transcript, I generate an array by encoding each character with the corresponding index into the alphabet dictionary. My model will output a tensor having lenght equal to the time length of the mfcc feature tensor, and I would like to have a label tensor with the same length, i.e., by aligning the characters and/or word encoding into the label tensor to the timing of utterancing of characters/words in the audio file.
In order to better clarify what I mean, I leave below a python script which does what I want, bu in case of phoneme recognition. I'm trying to modify it to adapt to the case of character/word recognition, but I'm not sure about the correct way to identify utterances in the audio. In the case shown below, the phonemes file transcript provides the start and end time instant of appearence of the phoneme into the audio file. Could be possible to have a similar result also for character/word recognition, without having prior knowladge of the timing of each character/words into the raw audio?
Thanks in advance for the answer.
Cheers

```
phn_name = str(label_files[i])
    wav_name = str(wav_files[i])

    if (wav_name.startswith("SA")):  # specific for TIMIT: these files contain strong dialects; don't use them
        continue

    # Get MFCC of the WAV
    X_val, total_frames = create_mfcc(wav_name,
                                      feat_args,
                                      feat_order) # get 3 or 4 levels: 0th, 1st, 2nd (and 3rd) derivative (=> 3*13 + 1 = 39 * num_levels coefficients)
                                      # max_sample_len)
    total_frames = int(total_frames)

    X.append(X_val)

    # Get phonemes and valid frame numbers out of .phn files
    total_duration = get_total_duration(phn_name)
    fr = open(phn_name)

    # some .PHN files don't start at 0. Set default phoneme to silence (expected at the end of phoneme_set_list)
    y_vals = np.zeros(total_frames) + phoneme_classes[phoneme_set_list[-1]]
    valid_frames_vals = []

    for line in fr:
        [start_time, end_time, phoneme] = line.rstrip('\n').split()
        start_time = int(start_time)
        end_time = int(end_time)
        start_ind = int(np.round(start_time / (total_duration / total_frames)))
        end_ind = int(np.round(end_time / (total_duration / total_frames)))

        valid_ind = int((start_ind + end_ind) / 2)
        valid_frames_vals.append(valid_ind)

        phoneme_num = phoneme_classes[phoneme]
        # check that phoneme is found in dict
        if (phoneme_num == -1):
            logger.error("In file: %s, phoneme not found: %s", phn_name, phoneme)
            pdb.set_trace()
        y_vals[start_ind:end_ind] = phoneme_num

        if verbose and logger:
            logger.debug('%s', (total_frames / float(total_duration)))
            logger.debug('TIME  start: %s end: %s, phoneme: %s, class: %s', start_time, end_time, phoneme,
                         phoneme_num)
            logger.debug('FRAME start: %s end: %s, phoneme: %s, class: %s', start_ind, end_ind, phoneme,
                         phoneme_num)
    fr.close()
```